# move-adobject user cross-domain

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to move a user object from one AD domain to another both domains are in the same forest.
By running:

```
Move-ADObject -Identity $User.ObjectGUID -Server $Source -TargetServer $Target -TargetPath $TargetOU
```

I get an error:

```
Move-ADObject : This object may not be moved across domain boundaries either because cross-domain moves for this class are disallowed, or the object has some special characteristics, e.g.: t
rust account or restricted RID, which prevent its move
```

1. $target its taget DC FQDN
2. $Source its source DC FQDN
3. forest level 2016

Checked if $target and $source are role holders. Both servers have PDCEmulator, RIDMaster, InfrastructureMaster
The user under which the command is run is Enterprice Admin and Domain Admin
Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced ObjectGUID with distinguishedName in the source object that I moved and in the target object that I moved and it all worked for me

Answer (score 0):

According to the [list of Windows System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--8200-8999-#error_ds_illegal_xdom_move_operation), that error is:

> **ERROR_DS_ILLEGAL_XDOM_MOVE_OPERATION**
>
> 8492 (0x212C)
>
> This object may not be moved across domain boundaries either because cross-domain moves for this class are disallowed, or the object has some special characteristics, e.g.: trust account or restricted RID, which prevent its move.

Look at the page that lists all the constraints for cross-domain moves, search the page for "ERROR_DS_ILLEGAL_XDOM_MOVE_OPERATION", and look at each one that returns that error if it is not met, and see if any of those applies to your situation. It might be something to do with the object you're trying to move.